# Imitating an on-paste URL event JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

Using jasmine to test some javascript code and I need to simulate an on-paste URL event. I've tried looking for something similar but I've only found something that simulates a on-paste event which originates from here

[How do I capture the input value on a paste event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902455/how-do-i-capture-the-input-value-on-a-paste-event)

```
$('textarea').trigger("paste");
```

Anyone have any idea on how to imitate an on-paste URL event?

EDIT1: The first duplicate statement only addresses intercepting a paste event not creating one. The second duplicate only addresses on creating a on-paste event not an on-paste URL event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intercept paste event in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035071/intercept-paste-event-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fire a "paste" event in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789975/fire-a-paste-event-in-javascript)